# Prevent Full-Screen on Presentation Start

Tags: user-interface, slideshows

Because my presentation will be given remotely, and I will go in and out of presentation mode often while engaging with the audience, I do not want Mathematica to go full-screen when I click "Start Presentation".  As it stands, it goes to full-screen and then it requires two clicks to go out of full screen, which is incredibly disruptive.  I want it to go full-window, instead.

**How can I prevent Mathematica from entering full-screen mode when starting a presentation, and instead go full-window?**